# how to upload a file (excel or csv) this should read the file in nodejs and update in the database mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

how  to upload a file which should except only excel or csv file and read the file by using nodejs and update in the database table (mongodb)

front end = angular5
backend = nodejs and mongodb

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Do you mind providing any detail at all? What have you tried so far? Provide code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side i.e node You will need `Multer` to upload files and set **type** to uploaded files, `fs` (Node Inbuilt) library to work with files, You will need `csv` package to parse data in that file, `Mongoose-ODM` to save that to MongoDB.

Next time be specific with your answer and show what you have tried till now.